# How to start a java file from a javascript file (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, java

Hello I have got a jar file lavalink to be exact which is basically a music module now i would like to start the jar file from my index.js(Main bot file) as I am not in the financial state to pay for a separate host for the lavalink server and would like to start and use the lavalink server in the same hosting container

No I am not running it in a browser I am using discord.js wrapper to interact with the discord API to make a backend program

Comment: in node you can execture command line commands https://stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-node-js/ 
- on which operating system is your node applicaion?

Comment: ubuntu 18 something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Installation

Install child process `npm i child-process` this allows you to execute shell comands

#### Command

give the exec function as first parameter your command

- `exec("cd ~/<path-to-directory-jarFile>  && java -jar Myjar_file.jar`
- `cd ~/<path-to-directory-jarFile>` goes in the directory where your jar file is
- `java -jar Myjar_file.jar` executes your jar file
- the `&&` executes your commands consecutevely first the one before then the one after

Example

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec("cd ~/<path-to-directory-jarFile>  && java -jar Myjar_file.jar ", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

Executing Shell Commands in NodeJS:

- https://stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-node-js/

Comment: i am a little stupid so can i ask will the path be home/container/src or just /src cuz in hostings we get a container in their home directory so our path will be relative to our container out the hosting's home dir?

Comment: I would recommend using relative path the tild stands for your home directory so you can do
`~/container/src`

Comment: The benefit is that if you move your project to a different unix system it will still work and you don't have to update your path

Comment: Alex it wowrked but i needed to change something writing this to let you know ```exec("cd ~/  && java -jar Lavalink.jar ", (error, stdout, stderr) => {``` this cded into my container if i added cd ~/container it went to home/container/container

Comment: @EliteGaming what did you change, the path to ~/ ?If you think this was helpful you can mark it as accepted the sign below the up-/downvote sign.